# Model selection in LASSO Regression

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, multiple-regression, mathematical-statistics, multivariate-analysis

I fitted lasso regression to "diabetes" data from Efron paper (2004).

I had the plot of the coefficients path, but how to know which the best model from this fitting/plot?

Comment: How are you defining "best model"?

Comment: @Matthew Drury , for example if I have ten variables then I will say those three variables are contributed for the response more, I will just include those three out of ten in my final/best model

Comment: If you want a three variable model, choose the value of $\lambda$ that gives you the best performing lasso model with three predictors.

Comment: ## Is that mean, there is no criteria such as AIC and BIC to choose between models. ## based on what the best performing lasso model.